# Pass variable from config to factory in AngularJS and UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to make a search in an http call with a different value depending on the view that I'm in.

My factory looks like this:

```
.factory('SearchService', ['$http','$filter', function($http, $filter) {

  var service = {

    getAllExhibitors : function () {
        var searchindex = 'Berliner';
        var url = '...';
        var config = {
            params: {
                search: searchindex
            },
            cache:true
        };
        $http.get(url, config).then(function (data) {
          service.datafairs = data.data.rows;
          ...
        });
    }...
```

As you can see I'm passing a hardcoded variable `searchindex` as parameter for the search.

Could I set this variable depending on the view I'm in?

My config for the router looks like this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider) {

  var berlinerState = {
    name: 'berliner',
    url: '/berlinerliste/',
    views: {
      'header': {   
        templateUrl: 'header.htm'   
      },
      'main':{    
        templateUrl: 'bl2017.htm'    
      }
    }
  }

  var koelnerState = {
    name: 'koelner',
    url: '/koelnerliste/',
    views: {
      'header': {   
        templateUrl: 'header.htm'   
      },
      'main':{    
        templateUrl: 'kl2017.htm'    
      }
    }
  }

  ...
```

For example, that on /berlinerliste, `searchindex = X` and on /koelnerliste, `searchindex = Y`

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

From the controller when you call your factory, you could be pass the actual state name and based on this value define the searchIndex on the getAllExhibitors method.

```
getAllExhibitors : function (stateName) {
    var searchindex = '';
    var url = '...';
    var config = {
        params: {
            search: searchindex
        },
        cache:true
    };
    if(stateName === 'berliner'){
       config.params.search = 'asdf'
    }
    .... 

    $http.get(url, config).then(function (data) {
      service.datafairs = data.data.rows;
      ...
    });
}...
```

and from your controller inject the $state service and send to the method the value of `$state.current.name`

Another way it is inject the $state service directly on your service, like this:

```
.factory('SearchService', ['$http','$filter','$state', function($http, $filter, $state){

      var service = {

    getAllExhibitors : function () {
        var searchindex = 'Berliner';
        var url = '...';
        var config = {
            params: {
                search: searchindex
            },
            cache:true
        };
        if($state.current.name === 'berliner') {
            config.params.search = 'asdf'
        }
    ....
        $http.get(url, config).then(function (data) {
          service.datafairs = data.data.rows;
      ...
    });
}...
```

Comment: When i do console.log($state);, current comes back empty!

Comment: Where are you do it the console.log($state)?

Comment: In the controller. I managed to get the state using a $watch function in the controller. Now I'm looking into how to pass this new $scope variable with the state name to the factory...

Comment: Can you add a controller to your example?

Answer (score 0):

When working with asynchronous APIs such $http, it is best to **return** promises:

```
app.service('SearchService', function($http, $filter) {    
    this.getAllExhibitors = function (searchArg) {
        var searchindex = searchArg || 'Berliner';
        var url = '...';
        var config = {
            params: {
                search: searchindex
            },
            cache:true
        };
        //RETURN promise
        ͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟ $http.get(url, config).then(function (response) {
              ͟r͟e͟t͟u͟r͟n͟  response.data.rows;              
        });
    };
});
```

Then in the controller, extract data from the promise:

```
app.controller("viewController", function($scope, SearchService, $state) {
    var searchArg = $state.current.name;
    var promise = SearchService.getAllExhibitors(searchArg);
    promise.then(function(rows) {
        $scope.rows = rows;
    });  
});
```

Also notice the the `getAllExhibitors` function has been modified to accept a `search` argument.

The [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) is a very useful thing that isn't used enough.